# How do GNU Radio input and output buffers work?

Tags: python, c++, buffer, gnuradio

I'm new to GNU Radio and having problems with understanding how input and output buffers work.

I wish to make a block with 1 input and 2 output ports. Furthermore, I want to divide a fixed size input into 2 output streams that have the same number of items.

At the very beginning, I made a block that has 1 input and 1 output port. It receives 4 elements and should put every other on the output port, i.e. for input values 1, 2, 3 and 4, it should output 1 and 3. I've overridden the forecast and general work method in the following way (adding the printf functions for easier debuging):

```
void test_block_impl::forecast (int noutput_items, gr_vector_int &ninput_items_required)
    {
      printf("Forcast, number of noutput_items %d\n", noutput_items);
      ninput_items_required[0] = noutput_items * 2;
      printf("Forcast, required input items %d\n", ninput_items_required[0]);
    }


int test_block_impl::general_work (int noutput_items,
                       gr_vector_int &ninput_items,
                       gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
                       gr_vector_void_star &output_items)
    {
      const float *in = (const float *) input_items[0];
      float *out = (float *) output_items[0];
      int num_inputitems = ninput_items[0];

      printf("General work, number of input items %d, number of output items %d\n", num_inputitems, noutput_items);
      for (int i = 0; i < num_inputitems ; i++)
      {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
          out[ i/2 ] = in[i];
          printf("out %f, in %f\n", out[i/2], in[i]);
        }
      }
      consume_each (noutput_items*2); // or should I put num_inputitems

      // Tell runtime system how many output items we produced.
      return noutput_items*2;
    }
```

I also called `set_max_noutput_items(2)` in the constructor.
I was hoping that the forecast function will tell the block that it needs an input of size 4 and than after that the general work function will process those items and output only every second one.

Unfortunately, after writing a Python test, I got a lot of unexpected results so I figured I didn't understand correctly the concept of buffers.
For the test:

```
    src_data = array ( [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])

    expected_result1 = (1.0, 3.0, 5.0)

    src = blocks.vector_source_f(src_data)
    dmx = tutorial.test_block(number)
    dst1 = blocks.vector_sink_f()

    self.tb.connect(src, dmx)
    self.tb.connect(dmx, dst1)
    self.tb.run (4)
```

I've recieved:

```
4: Forcast, number of noutput_items 2
4: Forcast, required input items 4
4: Forcast, number of noutput_items 1
4: Forcast, required input items 2
4: Forcast, number of noutput_items 2
4: Forcast, required input items 4
4: General work, number of input items 6, number of output items 2
4: out 1.000000, in 1.000000
4: out 3.000000, in 3.000000
4: out 5.000000, in 5.000000
4: Forcast, number of noutput_items 2
4: Forcast, required input items 4
4: Forcast, number of noutput_items 1
4: Forcast, required input items 2
4: General work, number of input items 2, number of output items 1
4: out 5.000000, in 5.000000
4: Forcast, number of noutput_items 2
4: Forcast, required input items 4
4: Forcast, number of noutput_items 1
4: Forcast, required input items 2
4: (1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0)
```

If somebody can help me understand from where did GNU Radio get those zeros and why does it call the forecast method in that order? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that `general_work` should return the number of output produced in this method call and `consume` should receive the number or input elements it will process. So in my case for getting the expected result, I should call consume_each with ninput_items (`consume_each(ninput_items)`) and `return ninput_items/2`